# Can not load file or assembly PX.Payroll and PX.Objects.PR assembly during publish of the package

Tags: c#, magento, e-commerce, customization, acumatica

I have an Acumatica of version 22.105.0031. I get an error when I try to publish the package from customization package.

[image: Compilation pane screenshot]

I can publish the package in Customization Projects SM204505 screen.

After doing some research I have found that new version of Acumatica contains *PX.Payroll.WebServiceClient.dll* instead of *PX.Payroll.dll*.
New 22.105.0031 version

[image: 22.105.0031 version]

Old 21.218.0027 version

[image: 21.218.0027 version]

Initially I have read this article.
[Error while loading PX.Payrol].(https://community.acumatica.com/customizations-187/error-loading-px-payroll-dll-when-publishing-customizations-in-2022-r1-problem-and-solution-9261)

How to publish the package without getting that error, for example when I need to publish with cleanup?

Comment: Try a clean build. Looks like you are still getting older libraries when you build.  You may need to delete references from your project if older libraries are still part of your project.

Comment: If applicable, verify that your extension project Acumatica references point to the site where you are deploying the customization. As community site suggest, in Acumatica ERP Configuration wizard, you can go to Perform Application Maintenance, select your site and then use down arrow button Update only Website to repair Acumatica files.

Answer (score 2):

I shared a report of this bug and a likely solution in private to one of the members of the payroll team three months ago, after having experienced this issue multiple times. Not sure if it has been filed and/or fixed at this point, but here it is in case someone from Acumatica want to give it a shot.

The root cause is the version number of PX.Payroll.DLL that is older in 2022 R1 than 2021. Due to the way Windows Installer handles upgrades and how the Acumatica MSI is designed, the file ends up being deleted instead of updated during the upgrade.

[Version numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUyrE.jpg)

The solution for those impacted is to uninstall Acumatica manually, install it angain and then run the Upgrade site process again. You may also simply copy the missing file to the bin directory.

Comment: One of my colleagues said that we can do "Perform Application Maintenance" and upgrade the Acumatica instance. I did it but that did not work for me.

Comment: Did you uninstall Acumatica from Add/Remove Programs and reinstall it before doing this? If you don’t see PX.Payroll.DLL in Files\bin, it’s not going to work.

Comment: No. I just did "Perform Application Maintenance" right after creating the instance.

Comment: That’s the problem - issue occurs while installing the MSI package. You have to uninstall from Add/Remove Programs and reinstall it before you do “Perform Application Maintenance” again. PX.Payroll.DLL is missing from the Acumatica files directory otherwise…